# Passing collection from CompositeView to CollectionView

Tags: marionette

I am rendering a table contains rows of content along with a button-group of buttons which its number of buttons could varied based on state.  Below is overall views relationship.

[image: overall views relationship]

Issue is CompositeView (row) won't pass Backbone.Collection to CollectionView (buttons).

**row**

```
Row.Main = Marionette.CompositeView.extend ({
    template : template,
    tagName  : 'tr',
    itemView: app.Row.Buttons.Main,
    itemViewContainer: '#buttons',
    itemViewOptions: {
       collection: this.collection
    }
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = app.request ('buttons:entities');

    }
});
```

**buttons**

```
Buttons.Main = Marionette.CollectionView.extend ({
    itemView: app.Row.Button.Main,

    initialize: function (options) {
        console.log ('options: %o', options);
        // this.collection = app.request ('buttons:entities'); 
    };
});
```

In buttons, `options.model` contains model from row collection but `options.collection` is always undefined.

If I uncomment `this.collection = app.request ('buttons:entities')` in buttons, I get 4 rows button-group, which it should display only 1 row of button-group:

[image]

Wondering how to pass collection from CompositeView to CollectionView? or is there a better approach?

Marionette ver 1.8.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Workaround: break the CompositeView (row) and CollectionView (buttons) chain with row becomes ItemView, then manually create a button-group `Marionette.Region` then `show` CollectionView of buttons.

Comment: Running into this as well, as I need to check the collection to apply logic to the model's view (whether to display a heading), i also looked into a solution similar to the above but then ran into too many issues with saving / deleting in my sub views.  Sigh!